# How can I run MSVC build tools (e.g. lib.exe) on an Azure Agent?

Tags: c++, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, cicd

I need to combine several static libraries (built from C++ code) for windows on an Azure (Microsoft-hosted) build agent. Locally, I can do this with `lib.exe` (part of the MSVC build tools).

I'm trying to run `lib.exe` in a script task, but the executable is not found. I've thought about manually adding the path for MSVC in the script and try like this, but that seems like a very fragile solution.

Can anybody give me a hint as to how to achieve this?

Comment: I'm afraid you may not be able to do it unless you set up your private agent. 
You could try using Linux agent/commands for same purpose which may have the preinstalled CLI tools. But that's not very promising as well.

Comment: Not an answer, but there is an [open issue with a workaround](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/9737). If it works for you you should post it as an answer.

Comment: @levangode: can I merge static libs built on windows with MSVC with e.g. `libtool` on Linux? I don't know enough about object formats

Comment: Thanks @Botje - I'm going to try that workaround.
Another idea I had was try to declare an additional Cmake library target and use `target_link_libraries`

Comment: @Sidelobe I meant Linux might have its own tools for achieving whatever you are doing with `lib.exe`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the commands described in this [workaround](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/9737), I was able to get it up and running.

I added this to the beginning of my `script` step (on windows agent):

```
pushd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\"
for /f "delims=" %%x in ('.\vswhere.exe -latest -property InstallationPath') do set VSPATH=%%x
popd
call "%VSPATH%\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat" x64
```

After this, I can call e.g. `lib.exe`. What's great about this is that it's not tied to a specific VS version/path.

Thanks go out [@Botje](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1548468/botje) for posting the link in their comment above - much appreciated!